# Product authentication check

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, webforms

I have an online store built in Woocommerce and I would like to add some kind of a form in which customers will enter a unique number that will as result show them a page with certification details of that particular product (product details, purchase date, warranty, etc.).

I tried to google it, but couldn't find any code or plugin. I found one website that has something similar to what I want to do. The website is https: //www. trusted. com/ check-authenticity

Does anyoune have an idea how could I do this using code or if there is some plugin that will do the job? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please if this paid extension from Woo-commerce can help in this situation.

**Returns and Warranty Requests – RMA Management**

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/warranty-and-returns/

**With this plugin, you can:**

> 1. Add a warranty to your products Sell (paid or free) a warranty as an
>      add-on to your products
> 2. Define the term/length of your warranty for
>      each product
> 3. Define the cost of the warranty for each product
> 4. Have
>      multiple terms and costs for warranties on a single product5
> 5. **Give your
>      customers a way to request a warranty via a form or directly within
>      their order details**
> 6. Manage the warranty and return directly in
>      WooCommerce

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/warranty-and-returns/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps in one part, but the most important part of the workflow is giving the ability to customers to input in a form a unique product number that only this particular customer. By submitting this unique number, the customer gets the access to a page that is associated only with a product that he/she has purchased. The page will contain the information such as date of purchase, payment type, warranty information etc. This information would have to be added manually which is ok.